# How to display name under photo in a foreach loop

Tags: php, html

Edit: I'm using php to accomplish this.

I'm making a page that draws information from a database (name, photo path) and I want it to show the picture and then the name of who it is underneath.

```
foreach ($result_array as $la ) {
    $firstname = $la['first_name'];
    $lastname = $la['last_name'];
    $fullname = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
    $image = $la['photo'];
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width="100px" height="100px" alt="'.$fullname.'"/> '.$fullname.' ';
}
```

As of now, the name is displayed next to the photo and just looks bad. How would I go about making the name appear below the photo?

Comment: This is just HTML ... just add `<p> '.$fullname.' </p>`

Comment: build the html to do what you want, then build some php to output html just like that... e.g. `<img ...><br />$fullname`

Comment: @VincentDecaux When I do that the nice grid of photos disappears. Is there a way to keep the grid as well as have the name underneath it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While a little more code than simply adding a line break, you could wrap your image in a `<figure>` and add a `<figcaption>` after your `<img>`.

```
foreach ($result_array as $la ) {
$firstname = $la['first_name'];
$lastname = $la['last_name'];
$fullname = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
$image = $la['photo'];
echo '<figure><img src="' . $image . '" width="100px" height="100px" alt="'.$fullname.'"/><figcaption>'.$fullname.'</figcaption></figure>';
}
```

To display multiple images per line, add the following to your CSS:

```
figure {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Check it out in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jritchey/f26t38gc/).

Comment: That still makes it so that there is only one image per line.

Comment: I have updated my answer to address multiple images.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Add `<br>` to create a line break

```
foreach ($result_array as $la ) {
    $firstname = $la['first_name'];
    $lastname = $la['last_name'];
    $fullname = $firstname . ' ' . $lastname;
    $image = $la['photo'];
    echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width="100px" height="100px" alt="'.$fullname.'"/> <br>'.$fullname.' ';
}
```

Comment: That makes it so that there is only one image per line. If I don't have the name all the images show up in a nice grid. Is there a way to keep the grid but also have the name below?

Comment: @user3342038 you will have to design html for it and then substitute the values there. Or may be `<table>` design in that case.

Answer (score 0):

There are different options for this depending on your needs. A simple solution is to add a line break after the image:

```
echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width="100px" height="100px" alt="'.$fullname.'"/><br /'.$fullname.' ';
```

If you want more control on styling, you can wrap the name in a div or span and assign a class to style it further with CSS:

```
echo '<img src="' . $image . '" width="100px" height="100px" alt="'.$fullname.'"/><div class="imagename">'.$fullname.'</div>';
```

Of course you could also wrap the entire image and text in a div, with or without the full name in its own div within there for further styling flexibility.